# how to change swipe tabs text size for different screen size? I am using fragments and view pager to create swipe tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

here is my java code where i set tabs and its text

```
 ublic class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
//Tab Tiles
private String [] tabs;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //initilization 
    viewPager =(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
     tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
    //Hiding Title bar
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

    //Adding tabs 

    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
    }//for each
```

and my manifest file is

```
       <activity
        android:name="com.galleryview.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The text size of tabs is good for normal phones but on tablet it looks too small..any idea how to do it in easy way ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setCustomView` method and create a custom layout with different text sizes from dimens.xml file using [configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

**MainActivity.java**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
TextView tv = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.customTextView, null);
tv.setText(tab_name);
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tv).setTabListener(this));
```

**customTextView.xml** on **layout** folder

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/actionbar_tab_text_size" />
```

**dimens.xml** on **values** folder

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="actionbar_tab_text_size">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

**dimens.xml** on **values-large** folder

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="actionbar_tab_text_size">20sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: thanks a ton...its working, i am able to change text size however when i put these lines 

    String [] tabs = {"FINISHED", "UNFINISHED"};
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
     tv.setText(tab_name);
 actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setCustomView(tv).setTabListener(this));
}//for each

this is only setting tab 2 " UNFINISHED" and  first tab is blank..do you have any idea what i miss again ? 
Thank you so much for help

Comment: i got it, i should also put 
       TextView tv = (TextView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabstextview, null);  in loop... 
thank you very much for simple solution.... :)