# increase size of swipeable tabs text

Tags: android, tabs, swipe, text-size

I recently developed an app, which has swipeable tabs, I have taken the tabs text in my java code, I want to increase the size of the tabs text, how can it be done..

The following is the sample code,

```
  private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "मुख्य समाचार", "स्टेट", "दुनिया" ,"राष्ट्रीय" ,"खेल" ,"व्यापार" ,"मनोरंजन" ,"स्वास्थ्य" ,"लाइफस्टाइल" ,"क्रिकेट" ,"ऐशिया" ,"अमेरिका" , "फ़ुटबॉल" , "मध्य प्रदेश", "छत्‍तीसगढ़" , "महाराष्ट्र" , "गोवा" , "उत्तर प्रदेश"};


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         ..........
         .............
```

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24822492/how-to-change-swipe-tabs-text-size-for-different-screen-size-i-am-using-fragmen)

Comment: Check the answer for [ActionBar tabs set dynamic width according to screen width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29339797/actionbar-tabs-set-dynamic-width-according-to-screen-width/29428695#29428695)

Comment: [Check an answer for your question ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47154904/7437508)

Comment: [please chek this link for answer ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47154904/7437508)

Answer (score 0):

Skynet has right link of solution and may be below is one another solution to set size programmatically. *Use it after adding all tabs.*

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = this.mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,20);      
        }
```

Comment: hey, i want to do it programatticaly that you gave the solution, the only problem is that , it says that , can't use getTabWidget for string types array
this is the msg shown..

Cannot invoke getTabWidget() on the array type String[]

Comment: Here  in  **mTabHost.getTabWidget()** mTabHost is instance of **TabHost** .

Can you show snippet how you are adding tabs to your activity.