# android font size of tabs

Tags: android, tabs

i ask this quest for a few time ago , but i get no solutions :(
my problem is, that i have an android app with a tab activity, where i have to set the font size of my tabs, but i don't know how.

in my activity i set my tabs programmatically:

```
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("MY TAB 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("MY TAB 2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("MY TAB 3"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Problem is, that the last 1 - 2 letters will be cut, so i have to set the font size smaller, but how?

i hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Write these below codes in styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTabLayout" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyTabTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

And in your tablayout, set the style like below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
     style="@style/MyTabLayout"
     android:layout_width="width"
     android:layout_height="height"/>
```

Comment: You should not use `dp` in fonts. Use `sp`

Comment: If this solution doesn't work for you & your tab text is multiline; Check out my answer here for solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48797329/700693

Answer (score 2):

try this

Create an xml layout named custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tab"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

than in your activity set text size programaticlly like below code

```
TextView tabOne = (TextView) 
LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
tabOne.setText("ONE");
tabOne.setTextSize(14); // set font size as per your requirement 
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the font size programmatically, you can use java reflection to access the integer field **tabTextSize** in the **TabLayout** class and set the font size as per your requirement.

```
public static void updateTabLayoutFontSize(TabLayout tabLayout, int textSizeInPixel) {
  try {
     Field mCursorDrawableRes = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("tabTextSize");
     mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
     mCursorDrawableRes.set(tabLayout, textSizeInPixel);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d("TAG1", "Failed to update tablayout font using reflection");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you set text_size directly in style of tab layout,
it doesn't work!!
you have to set it into a style which has 
parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"

```
<style name="tab_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@fonts/iransans_b</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/textSize_Large</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<style name="Tab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/tab_text</item>
</style>


 <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                 android:id="@+id/item_tabs"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_dp_65"
                 style="@style/Tab"/>
```

and also this is a full style for tab:

```
 <style name="Tab_WithBackground" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/purple</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@drawable/tab_text_color</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="tabMaxWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/margin_dp_80</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/tab_text</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#If you dont want to use style.xml and do by prgramatically the Use this in your xml layout. #
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_Layout_dashboard"
                android:layout_below="@id/ll_profile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.15"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_below="@id/tab_Layout_dashboard"
                android:id="@+id/pager_tutor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.85"
                />


#In your activity or fragment use this method#

 private void changeTabsFont() {
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/"+ Constants.FontStyle);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tab_layout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(font);
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(15);

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## This code works for Tablayout change text color,type face(Font style) and also Text size. IF this works for you also then make correct so other user can easily solve his/her problem

Answer (score 0):

also try:

```
<style name="MyCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
   <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done the following:

Create a attrs.xml entry like this

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="SegmentedTabLayout">
    <attr name="fontSize" format="dimension" />
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Then create a font size property and initialise method that you'll call in the constructor like this

```
public float FontSize { get; set; }

private void InitializeAttrs(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
{
    if (context == null || attrs == null)
            return;

    var styleAttributes = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.SegmentedTabLayout);

    if (styleAttributes == null)
        return;

    FontSize = styleAttributes.GetDimension(Resource.Styleable.SegmentedTabLayout_fontSize, -1);

    styleAttributes.Recycle();
}
```

Then I used the method of viral 9966 (improved it a little) and called it in the override NewTab method like this

```
public override Tab NewTab()
{
    var tab = base.NewTab();

    ChangeFontSize(tab);

    return tab;
}

private void ChangeFontSize(Tab tab)
{
    if (FontSize < 0)
        return;

    var tabViewGroup = (ViewGroup)tab.View;
    for (int i = 0; i < tabViewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
    {
        if (tabViewGroup.GetChildAt(i) is TextView textView)
        {
            textView.TextSize = FontSize;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

## 100% Working Code

```
fun TabLayout.customizeTabDesign() {
    val viewGroup = this.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    for (i: Int in 0..viewGroup.childCount) {
        val tabViewGroup = viewGroup.getChildAt(i) as ViewGroup?
        tabViewGroup?.let {
            for (j: Int in 0..tabViewGroup.childCount) {
                val tab = tabViewGroup.getChildAt(j)
                if (tab is TextView) {
                    tab.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "font.ttf")
                    tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 21f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```